# Twilio 'Longest Idle' ordering for matching Workers not working as expected

Tags: twilio, twilio-taskrouter

Multitasking enabled Workspace. TaskQueue1 has matching workers Woker1 and Worker2. Worker1 comes online (Presence set to 'Idle') first and then Worker2 comes online. A Task created for TaskQueue1 with Wokflow Queue also set as TaskQueue1. As expected, this Task gets reserved to Worker1. Worker1 accepts the Reservation and starts working.
**Scenario 1 :** Worker1 completes the Task (updates task.status=completed). Next a new Task created for same Task Queue and it gets reserved to Worker2, which satisfies 'Longest idle' ordering as expected.
**Scenario 2 :** Worker1 still working on the Task. Worker2 to goes to offline (presence set to 'Offline') and immediately comes back to online. Worker1 completes the Task (updates task.status=completed). Next a new Task created for same Task Queue, but this time the Task gets reserved again back to Worker1 even though Worker2 comes online when Worker1 working on first Task.
Could anyone please explain why the behavior is different in these 2 scenarios?

Comment: Twilio developer evangelist here. The team behind TaskRouter are going to investigate this to find out what is going on. If you want to be notified about this, it would be best if you contact [Twilio support](https://www.twilio.com/help/contact) and explain what is going on and what you expect.